# Browser can not read PHP generated CSS file

Tags: javascript, php, css, model-view-controller

I was creating my own CMS and I was going to use [rakaz.nl](http://rakaz.nl/2006/12/make-your-pages-load-faster-by-combining-and-compressing-javascript-and-css-files.html) PHP script for speeding up page load

I am using MVC structure and then I was forced to use this script in a controller

And finally I succeed to generate CSS file but browsers can not read the CSS file and error that the server responded NOT FOUND!

This is what I got in chrome console:

i.stack.imgur.com/N9oqT.jpg

And this is CSS file address:

mahdizakizadeh.me/style/base.min.css,type.min.css,fonticon.min.css,smiley.min.css

and site address:

mahdizakizadeh.me

note: Site Language is Persian.

Comment: this is [the console](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N9oqT.jpg), I dont know why but it can not read the file and error not found

Comment: Possibly the permissions on the file created? Or can you confirm that it's actually there?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean but the file created without any problem in [this link](http://mahdizakizadeh.me/style/base.min.css,type.min.css,fonticon.min.css,smiley.min.css)

Comment: Those are really long URLs. Check that they match up.

Comment: Those are correct. You can open the source and click on them to open them and see the files :(

Comment: Then perhaps they're being generated slower than the rest of the page and thus aren't loading?

Comment: So how can I solve it?

Comment: Honestly? Don't use php to generate a CSS file. Use something like Sass or SCSS that was designed for it.

Comment: Are u sure that code has no problem? I use SCSS for designing but this script reduse http connections. There are lots of peoples that use this script :(

Comment: Functionally it looks like it should work. So unless it's some bizarre config on your server, I don't know. Can you try it on a different server?

Comment: No I just have this one :(

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the problem lies within the css file name. Try to replace unnecessary signs from it (`.` and `,`). However, this hints that your webserver could be misconfigured.

If you try to load the following URL, the browser displays the CSS quite fine. If you check the browser console output again, you will notice that your webserver responds with the status code 404 NOT FOUND, even if the result contains the valid css.
http://mahdizakizadeh.me/style/base.min.css,type.min.css,fonticon.min.css,smiley.min.css

This is not the case with a simplified version of the URL. Check the following URL, that probably returns a part of the other css file. The status code is 200 - OK. 
http://mahdizakizadeh.me/style/base.min.css

If you insert this CSS into your webpage, the output looks ok to me.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000">
  <meta name="autor" content="Mahdi Zakizadeh">
  <meta name="description" content="دست نوشته ها و مطالب مورد علاقه من درباره طراحی، برنامه نویسی و عکاسی">
  <meta name="keywords" content="برف,درباره خودم,یزد,سیستم,اتفاقات روزمره">
  <title>دست نوشته | وبلاگ شخصی مهدی زکی زاده</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png">
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/base.min.css, type.min.css" />-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/base.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/smiley.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/fonticon.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/type.min.css">

  <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="/javascript/jquery.min.js,jquery.animate-colors.min.js,base.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You have a similar problem with your javascript files.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. +1

Comment: So if I use / (or another sign) instead of , the problem might be solved? Yes the js files also has the problem because they also use this script :|

Comment: @user3341409 A slash would be the worst possible solution here. Try an underscore or give the file a static name if possible (e.g. minified.css). Additionally, you definitely should check the configuration of your webserver.

Comment: I used - instead of , but nothing changed. (I dont think server configuration  has problem with - char because I used it in a js file) I still think I have a mistake in my codes.

Comment: Thanks all. I found the problem. I blocked access for css and js files from htaccess and now codes works fine. thanks to all. :)